# kernel panic after exploiting dirty cow on kernel 3.13.0

Tags: ctf, dirty-cow

After exploiting the dirty cow vulnerabillity https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40839/ my ubuntu virtual machine keep getting a kernel panic after every reboot. What could possibly cause this behaviour?

the vm i tried to root was https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/hackfest2016-sedna,181/